# How to change Publish Code targetFremework from Higher version to lower version in .net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I am facing a problem .I have developed an application using .net framework 4.5 .
Now when I publish my application to domain. That domain has .net framework 2.0. So is there any way to change the target Framework higher to lower?

Comment: I don't think it will work on .net framework 2.0 if you develop it on frame work 4.5.

Comment: .net 4.5 has some extra libraries that are not supported by the .net 2 framework, `Linq` for example. you can change the target framework though in the project's properties page (right click project, not solution) and there under build->target framework

Comment: I did the same but now as you said I am facing the problem for System.Linq namespace. I add assembly for Linq in web config still facing problems.

Comment: Thanks I removed all the occurrence of using system.Linq and it works for me with .net framework 2.0.But there is no way to use linq with .net framework version 2.0?

Comment: to use **Linq** u need framework version > 2.0 for sure